# Persisting large files with Hibernate Annotations

Tags: hibernate, annotations, hibernate-annotations

I am using Hibernate Annotations for the first time in my web application.  In my bean, what type what annotations should I use to persist files uploaded by users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you're using the JPA annotations.  If so, you'll want to use the `@Lob` annotation for large data sets.  See [this page](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/MarkByteArrayFieldAsLob.htm) for an example.

[This page](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html) lists a little more information specific to Hibernate JPA.  Of interest:

> @Lob indicates that the property should be persisted in a Blob or a Clob depending on the property type: java.sql.Clob, Character[], char[] and java.lang.String will be persisted in a Clob. java.sql.Blob, Byte[], byte[] and serializable type will be persisted in a Blob.

Comment: There are actually two fields - one specifically for images file, the other for any arbitrary file.  These should both be handled as byte[] I presume?

Comment: You could do byte[], or if your fields are serializable, you could directly define them as that serializable type -- see here for an example: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/MapSerializableEntityToLob.htm